# Literature values for the molar absorptivity of Methylene Blue

Tags: dye

I am having trouble finding literature values for the molar absorptivity of MB dye from a scientific journal, preferably one that is recent.

I am also having trouble finding an explanation for why MB doesn't follow Beer's Law for high concentrations from a scientific journal.

I apologise if my english is hard to understand.

Comment: What is high  concentration and what is the absorbance curve like?

Comment: Wikipedia article mentions dimer formation.